# serde: speedup custom enum deserialization

Tags: rust, serde

My program parse big enough json document (30MB),
on machine with slow CPU it takes 70ms, I want to speedup the process,
and I find out that 27% of parsing take place into my `foo_document_type_deserialize`,
is it possible to improve this function, may be there is way to skip `String` allocation here: `let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;`?

I completly sure that strings that represent enum values doesn't contain special json characters like `\b \f \n  \r \t \" \\`, so it should be safe to work with unescaped string.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct FooDocument {
    // other fields...
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "foo_document_type_deserialize")]
    doc_type: FooDocumentType,
}

fn foo_document_type_deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<FooDocumentType, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    use self::FooDocumentType::*;
    let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match s.as_str() {
        "tir lim bom bom" => Ok(Var1),
        "hgga;hghau" => Ok(Var2),
        "hgueoqtyhit4t" => Ok(Var3),
        "Text" | "Type not detected" | "---" => Ok(Unknown),
        _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(format!(
            "Unsupported foo document type '{}'",
            s
        ))),
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub enum FooDocumentType {
    Unknown,
    Var1,
    Var2,
    Var3,
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid (but no expert) that there isn't much you can do. Did you compile your program with `--release`?

Comment: @hellow yes, and I replaced work `File` with `fs::read_to_string` + `serde_json::from_str`, because of https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/160 . Still too slow.

Comment: As you mention in your question, allocating a new `String` for each deserialization is likely contributiing to the performance issue here. Serde provides an `impl Deserialize for &str`. Can you use that instead of the `String` impl?

Comment: Instead of `let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;`, try this: `let s = <&str as Deserialize<'de>>::deserialize(deserializer)?;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The custom impl you've written is in a form that serde_derive can generate:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum FooDocumentType {
    #[serde(rename = "Text", alias = "Type not detected", alias = "---")]
    Unknown,
    #[serde(rename = "tir lim bom bom")]
    Var1,
    #[serde(rename = "hgga;hghau")]
    Var2,
    #[serde(rename = "hgueoqtyhit4t")]
    Var3,
}
```

The resulting derived code does not allocate memory and is about 2× faster in a quick microbenchmark compared to your code when I measure the following:

```
serde_json::from_str::<FooDocument>(r#"{"type":"hgga;hghau"}"#).unwrap()
```